# Joining two lists with LINQ throws

Tags: c#, list, linq, join

I have 2 lists on which I'm performing a left outer join as shown below:

```
class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class AvailableItem
{
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

var leftList = new List<Item>(); //Then populate
var rightList = new List<Item>(): //Then populate too

var list = (from l in leftList
            join r in rightList on l.Id equals r.Id into gp
            from sp in gp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new AvailableItem
            {
                IsAvailable = sp != null,
                Item = l
            }).ToList();
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: inner'

The exception is only thrown when `rightList` is not empty. If it's empty, `list` will contain all the items in `leftList`.

I've also tried changing the line:

```
join r in rightlist on l.Id equals r.Id into gp
```

to:

```
join r in rightlist on l equals r into gp
```

as it's the same items in both lists. However, I'd rather use the `Id` property just in case.

But the query still throws the same exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you define your list?

Comment: `r.Id` does not exist based on your models.

Comment: Change `join r in rightList on l.Id equals r.Id` to `join r in rightList on l.Id equals r.Item.Id`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Typo. My bad. `rightList` is also of type `List<Item>`.

Comment: 'AvailableItem' boolean seems to be in conflict with class name; also, class name already indicates the availability of the items, therefore using a boolean to indicate whether the item existed or not seems not necessary.

Comment: @JoeWu Another typo! Also, I need te `bool` property because I'm binding the list to a listview and use that property for the checkbox column.

Comment: The error you get only occurs if `rightList` is null.